# How to ignore special characters, as it was whitespace, on Irony parser

Tags: .net, irony

I am implementing a parser at Irony parser and I want to skip some special characters as <,>,(,), etc.

I want the parser to treat them as the space character. How can I add some characters at the ignore list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to be skipped in the parse tree, just use **MarkPunctuation**  for example:

> `MarkPunctuation("<", ">", "(", ")")`